# data.frame in a loop - R

Tags: r

In the script below I wish to fill the a data.frame with file name and different values but I always get the same values, how can I fix it?

Script:

```
folder <- "E:/Testry" 

i<-0;
k<-10;

for(filename in (paste0(folder,'/',list.files(folder))))
{
  print(filename)
  k<-sin(k);
  i<-cos(i);

  mydata  <- data.frame(i,k, list.files(folder))
  i<-i+1;
  k<-k-1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do this without a loop:

```
files <- list.files( folder )
i <- cos( seq.int( from = 0, by = 1, length.out = length(files) ) )
k <- sin( seq.int( from = 10, by = -1, length.out = length(files) ) )
mydata <- data.frame( "V1" = i, "V2" = k, "V3" = files )
```

So we're creating a vector for each of the columns you need, then inserting those into a brand new data frame. I'm not 100% against `for` loops, but R tends to be much more efficient in working this way.

Hopefully the `seq.int` call makes sense, if not see the help page, it's a very handy tool.

EDIT: I notice you're reassigning `i` and `k` twice each within your for loop, but that looks like something you've done by mistake, hence I haven't taken that into account here. Was that intentional? Did you want `i` and `k` to shift by 1 in each run of the loop, or by an amount determined by the result of the `sin` and `cos` functions?

OK, since you want the i and k values to change twice, here's another way:

```
new <- data.frame( files = list.files( folder ), i = NA, k = NA )
new$i[1]  <- cos(0)
new$k[1]  <- sin(10)
for( row in 2:nrow(new)){
    new$i[row] <- cos(new$i[row-1]+1)
    new$k[row] <- sin(new$k[row-1]-1)
}
```

Notice that within the `for` loop, each `[row]` depends on the one above it `[row-1]`

Comment: Yes, I want to change i and k in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating an empty data.frame before the loop:

```
mydata <- data.frame(numeric(0), numeric(0), character(0))
```

Then in the loop add rows with:

```
mydata <- rbind(mydata, data.frame(i, k, filename))
```

It's not the most efficient method but it should work.  If you need greater efficiency, preallocate space in the data.frame and replace rbind with assignments to the preallocated rows.